# Does App Engine Flexible automatically gzip responses?

Tags: google-app-engine

App Engine Standard supports automatic gzip compression of responses if the client has the correct Accept-Encoding and User-Agent headers set on the request. Info on this can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/how-requests-are-handled#Go_Responses).

I am running a project in the App Engine Flexible Beta and it does not auto compress the responses. Is auto response compression present on the Flexible Beta? If not, what is the recommended approach to compress responses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presently, App Engine Flexible Beta will not compress responses.  Most web servers can be configured to compress responses.  Which web server are you using?

Comment: I was interested in compression of JSON returned from my app server. It is written in Go. The go net/http package doesn't have default support for gzip compression, but there is a nice third party package available from the NY Times. Thanks for your help!